# gdb does not implement startup-with-shell under cygwin?

Tags: bash, gdb, escaping

I am doing this command:

```
gdb --args ../ncdump/ncdump file:///cygdrive/d/git/dap4/dap4_test/testfiles/test_atomic_array.nc.dap#dap4
```

and because it is being passed to bash, it persists in converting # to \#.
I could find no combination of quotes that could prevent this.

So, I decided to try the gdb command

```
set startup-with-shell off
```

but it does not work and

```
help set
```

does not show the command.
It does show a "set shell" command, but I assume
that just sets the shell to execute.

I am running gdb 7.9 under cygwin.
Can someone verify that this is not implemented
under Cygwin. Is there a work-around for either
my underlying problem (\#) or for missing startup-with-shell?

Comment: A nice workaround would be (if you can) to use "native" gdb from MinGW.

Comment: One more oddity. If I change '#dap4' to '?#dap4', it appears to pass thru correctly.

Comment: So I came up with workaround of sorts. It looks like the shell command to gdb (under cygwin) operates like startup-with-shell. So if I do 'set shell off' and if I pass the arguments to ncdump using the gdb r command, it seems to work. In any case, I am still curious about answers to my original question(s).